# D3 removal animation 'delayed' by updating - any way to prevent multiple calls to the same animation?

Tags: d3.js

I've got some D3 data that can be very quickly updated due to the user scrolling.

I have an issue with the removal animation, it appears to 'pause' when the user scrolls, due to the updating data.

It appears that the items are having the remove transition applied every update, which overrides the previous animation and seems to start 'easing' from scratch, thus making a very 'jerky' removal animation.

Is there any way to tell D3 to continue the existing transition named 'remove', if it exists instead of replacing it? I attempted this manually with `each`, `filter` and storing a `this.__isRemoving__` but it was very hacky, and it felt like I was fighting D3 (items were sometimes left when they should have been removed etc).

I've made an example of the behaviour, a very simple D3 bar graph. Pressing a button creates/adds/removes the data. If you select the checkbox it simulates updates, during the deletions.

Kind of linked to a previous question: [Removing items with a transition prevents them from being added during that period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70596918/removing-items-with-a-transition-prevents-them-from-being-added-during-that-peri)

```js
const dataset1 = [{
    name: "item 1",
    value: 200
  },
  {
    name: "item 2",
    value: 100
  }
];
const dataset2 = [{
  name: "item 1",
  value: 100
}];

function refresh(newDataset) {
  // Join new data with old elements, if any.
  let dataGroups = d3
    .select(".vis")
    .selectAll(".box")
    .data(newDataset, (d) => d.name);

  dataGroups.interrupt("remove");
  
  dataGroups.attr("opacity", 1);

  // Remove old elements as needed.
  dataGroups
    .exit()
    .transition("remove")
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("opacity", 0.2)
    .remove();

  // Create new elements as needed.
  const newGroups = dataGroups
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "box")
    .attr("height", 10)
    .attr("opacity", 0)

  newGroups.transition("add").duration(1000).attr("opacity", 1);

  // Merge and update
  dataGroups = newGroups.merge(dataGroups);

  dataGroups
    .attr("width", (d) => d.value)
    .attr("y", (d, i) => i * 12);
}

let currentDataset = undefined;
document.getElementById("button").onclick = () => {
  const newDataset = currentDataset === dataset1 ? dataset2 : dataset1;
  currentDataset = newDataset;
  refresh(newDataset);
};

setInterval(() => {
  if (document.getElementById("timerUpdate").checked && currentDataset) {
    currentDataset[0].value = Math.abs(currentDataset[0].value + (Math.random() - 0.5) * 70) % 300
    refresh(currentDataset);
  }
}, 500)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <button id="button">Add or remove an item</button>
  <div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="timerUpdate" name="scales">
  <label for="scales">Update the data every 200ms</label>
</div>

  <svg class="vis" width="300" height="30"></svg>

  <p>
    Click the button to cause an add or remove event.
  </p>

  <p>
    Check the box to enable data updates. The removal events 'restart' on every update.
  </p>

    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: To avoid confusion it might be worth adding a link to your previous question [*"Removing items with a transition prevents them from being added during that period"*](/q/70596918) that explains why you are interrupting the transition in the first place.

Comment: Firstly, the interrupted transition is **not** being restarted! It is cancelled altogether with a new transition starting off where the interrupted one stopped doing its work. Second thought on the overall design: do you think it is a good idea to have the duration of your removal lasting longer than your refresh cycle? Things will get really messy once data re-enters the chart while the corresponding bar is halfway through its own removal.

Comment: The refresh cycle in the actual application is actually tied to the user scrolling (it's drawing some connecting lines between two lists), so the frequency depends on the user. If the user is dragging to scroll, which causes a data update very frequently.

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to 'hack' this by adding a filter to check if the named transition already exists before applying the `add` and `remove` animation:

```
function filterIfTransitionPresent(name) {
  return function() {
    if (this.__transition) {
      return !Object.values(this.__transition).some(transition => transition.name === name);
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  };
}
```

It feels hacky, having to check the internal `__transition` state, but seems to work well.

I'm curious if people have any better solutions.

```js
const dataset1 = [{
    name: "item 1",
    value: 200
  },
  {
    name: "item 2",
    value: 100
  }
];
const dataset2 = [{
  name: "item 1",
  value: 100
}];

function refresh(newDataset) {
  // Join new data with old elements, if any.
  let dataGroups = d3
    .select(".vis")
    .selectAll(".box")
    .data(newDataset, (d) => d.name);

  dataGroups.interrupt("remove");
  
  dataGroups.attr("opacity", 1);

  // Remove old elements as needed.
  dataGroups
    .exit()
    .filter(filterIfTransitionPresent("remove"))
    .transition("remove")
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("opacity", 0.2)
    .remove();

  // Create new elements as needed.
  const newGroups = dataGroups
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "box")
    .attr("height", 10)
    .attr("opacity", 0)

  newGroups
    .filter(filterIfTransitionPresent("add"))
    .transition("add")
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("opacity", 1);

  // Merge and update
  dataGroups = newGroups.merge(dataGroups);

  dataGroups
    .attr("width", (d) => d.value)
    .attr("y", (d, i) => i * 12);
}

function filterIfTransitionPresent(name) {
  return function() {
    if (this.__transition) {
      return !Object.values(this.__transition).some(transition => transition.name === name);
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  };
}

let currentDataset = undefined;
document.getElementById("button").onclick = () => {
  const newDataset = currentDataset === dataset1 ? dataset2 : dataset1;
  currentDataset = newDataset;
  refresh(newDataset);
};

setInterval(() => {
  if (document.getElementById("timerUpdate").checked && currentDataset) {
    currentDataset[0].value = Math.abs(currentDataset[0].value + (Math.random() - 0.5) * 70) % 300
    refresh(currentDataset);
  }
}, 500)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <button id="button">Add or remove an item</button>
  <div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="timerUpdate" name="scales">
  <label for="scales">Update the data every 200ms</label>
</div>

  <svg class="vis" width="300" height="30"></svg>

  <p>
    Click the button to cause an add or remove event.
  </p>

  <p>
    Check the box to enable data updates. The removal events 'restart' on every update.
  </p>

    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Still not sure about the UX of your design but instead of messing with D3‘s internals you could use [`d3.active()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition#active) to check for active transitions.